# Is there a way I can fill a column cell with a cell in another row based off relations between an ID and year

Tags: r, filter, multiple-columns

Using table 1, I want to fill the column 'Next Outcome' using the Outcome for the following year. Is there a way I can do with in R using an ID and following year?

**Table 1:**

| ID | Year | Outcome | Next Outcome |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2018 | Renewed |  |
| 123 | 2019 | Cancelled |  |
| 123 | 2020 | Renewed |  |

**Table 2:**

| ID | Year | Outcome | Next Outcome |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2018 | Renewed | Cancelled |
| 123 | 2019 | Cancelled | Renewed |
| 123 | 2020 | Renewed | NA |

I am able to do this in power Bi or excel but I have been struggling to find a solution in R.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dplyr::lead` in `mutate`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(next_outcome = dplyr::lead(Outcome))

#   ID Year   Outcome next_outcome
#1 123 2018   Renewed    Cancelled
#2 123 2019 Cancelled      Renewed
#3 123 2020   Renewed         <NA>
```

Data

```
df <- read.table(text = "ID Year    Outcome
                 123    2018    Renewed 
                 123    2019    Cancelled   
                 123    2020    Renewed", h = T)
```

Comment: If I had additional year and ID columns, how would I specify which columns to filter by?

Comment: I dont quite know what you mean - if you want to do it by `id` and `year` then use `group_by(id, year)` before the `mutate()` function. If that's not what you mean, please edit your question with this example and ping me and I'll edit my answer